# gnuplot error: Bad format character

Tags: gnuplot

Am new to gnuplot but need o use it urgently. This is the following set of commands I used:

```
set  terminal  latex
set output “conflict.tex”
set xtics ("random"  2, "sharing(0%)"  3, "sharing(10%)"  4, "sharing(25%)"   5, “sharing(50%)”  6, “stat”  7)
set ylabel “Conflict Percentage”
set xrange [0:9]
set yrange [0:60]
set xlabel “Traces”
set boxwidth 0.3
set style fill
plot 'D:\Utility Softwares\conflicts.dat' with boxes
```

after which i get "Bad format character" and don't know why

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

Recently I had the same problem with escaping ("Bad format character") in xtics().

This should work:

```
set xtics ("random"  2, "sharing(0\%%)"  1, ...)
```

What helped me, was to look at the generated tex file.

Comment: Interestingly, what worked for me was `\\%` instead of `\%%`

Answer (score 0):

You have used two types of quotation mark:

```
“...” and "..."
```

I guess it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem are the non-ASCII quotation marks.  Replace them with `"`.

The next problem might be the `%` characters, since those are comment characters for LaTeX.  It might be necessary to escape them with a backslash: `\%`.

Finally, your data file could have a non-standard separator.  You might need to set the `datafile separator`.

Answer (score 0):

double the special character %
like this "%%"

Comment: Instead of writing this "sometext %" write this "sometext %%"