# gnuplot error: "Bad format character" despite "set datafile separator"

Tags: gnuplot

I'm non-native for English, so sorry for my poor English.

I use gnuplot 5.0.0 on MacOSX and execute next code.

```
plot "psd.dat" using 1:2
```

and the content of my psd.dat file is following:

```
-500 14.51 15.12
-450 14.54 15.08
-400 14.57 15.04
-350 14.59 15.02
-300 14.60 14.96
-250 14.66 14.95
-150 14.71 14.90
-100 14.76 14.87
-50 14.79 14.83
0 14.85 14.85
50 14.84 14.78
100 14.89 14.74
150 14.93 14.72
200 14.98 14.70
250 15.02 14.68
300 15.05 14.66
350 15.12 14.64
400 15.16 14.63
450 15.21 14.62
500 15.26 14.60
```

But I had next error.

```
Bad format character
```

I referred to [gnuplot error: Bad format character | stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342483/gnuplot-error-bad-format-character) and execute:

```
set datafile separator whitespace
```

But even after I execute it, I also had "Bad format character" error.
I think what I did is very basic, so I have no idea why I had this error.
Do you have any idea to solve it? Please tell me.

P.S.
After I solve this error, I'd like to execute next code.

```
set autoscale fix
set format x "%d"
set format y "%.1f"
f(x) = a*x+b
a = 50000
b = 0
fit [-500:500] f(x) "psd.dat" using 1:(($2 - $3)/($2 + $3)) via a,b
plot "psd.dat" using 1:(($2 - $3)/($2 + $3)*a+b) w p, f(x)
set terminal tikz
set output "psd.tex"
replot
set terminal pdf
set output "psd.pdf"
replot
set terminal aqua
```

Comment: The format string "%d" in the second line of your script is bad. Nothing wrong with your data or the datafile separator. Check "help format specifier".

Comment: Btw., you shouldn't give a starting value of zero to a fit parameter. A linear function like yours will converge anyway, but this can go wrong for more complicated fits.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your data.

Gnuplot does not evaluate the format strings when you enter them (with `set format`), but only when the next plot is made.

"%d" is not a valid format string, so you get an error.